# How to use $this->methodname in PHP session_set_save_handle?

Tags: php, session

I have a Session class that has all my on_session_write, on_session_read etc. methods inside the class. In my constructor function i have it initiate the

```
session_set_save_handler("on_session_start",   "on_session_end",
        "on_session_read",    "on_session_write",
        "on_session_destroy", "on_session_gc");
```

and also session_start() within this my only problem is the methods need to be called using $this-> because everything is within the class. How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
array($this,'methodName');
```

That's a callback to a method.

```
array('className','methodName');
```

That's a callback to a static method.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `array($this, 'methodName')` as an argument. Read more on <s>`http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php`</s>(dead link)